# upgrade to elementary loki on dell 6400

Tags: release-loki

I noticed that elementary os loki is only available in amd 64bit version.  my dell 6400 series laptop had below configuration. Need to know if loki can be installed.  currently its running elementary OS Freya.

CPU :  intel dual core

RAM :  4 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Loki should be working pretty well with this configuration. However, I suggest that you test it with an USB stick before installing Loki.